# Using the 'or' operator

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an error message for if the user doesn't input one of the options they are given, there are multiple options.

This is what I've tried so far:

```py
if crypto_choice == 'BTC' or 'BCH' or 'ETH' or 'LTC' or 'XRP':
    print("")
else:
    print("Error: Choose BTC, BCH or ETH")
    time.sleep(3)
    quit()
```

For example:
I set crypto_choice to 'trees'
The program then continues to run normally, ignoring the else, and the variable stays as trees.

I'm new to python and programming so I'm sorry if I'm being stupid, thanks in advance to anyone that helps me.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value basically you want to use `in` if you're going to test for multiple conditions

Comment: `crypto_choice == 'BTC' or 'BCH' or 'ETH' or 'LTC' or 'XRP'` == `(crypto_choice == 'BTC') or ('BCH') or ('ETH') or ('LTC') or ('XRP')` and non-empty string evaluates to True

Comment: Just use `crypto_choice in {'BTC', 'BCH', 'ETH', 'LTC', 'XRP'}`

Comment: @MrFuppes *multiple `a == b` conditions with `or` where one side of the equality is kept constant across conditions...

Answer (score 1):

Using lists is more pythonic and easier.

```py
    if crypto_choice in ['BTC', 'BCH', 'ETH', 'LTC', 'XRP']:
        print("")
    else:
        print("Error: Choose BTC, BCH or ETH")
        time.sleep(3)
        quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `crypto_choice ==` each option. A more efficient way would be to make an array and use `in`:

```
if crypto_choice in ["BTC", "BCH", "ETH", "LTC", "XRP"]:
  print("")
else:
  print("Error: Choose BTC, BCH or ETH")
  time.sleep(3)
  quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do

```
if crypto_choice == 'BTC' or crypto_choice == 'BCH' or crypto_choice == 'ETH' or 
crypto_choice == 'LTC' or crypto_choice == 'XRP':
    print("")

else:
    print("Error: Choose BTC, BCH or ETH")
```